# Parsing element on clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So I want to parse the h2 tag and save its text content into a constant after I the button "select" is clicked

```
<div className={"card " + (this.state.selected ? "methodSelected" : "")}>
    <h2 className="charge"></h2>
    <button onClick={this.selectMethod} href="#"className="btn return-btn">SELECT</button>
</div>
```

The function I'm using to setState after clicking the button

```
selectMethod = () => {
      this.setState({selected: true});
  }
```

Comment: Can you show, please, what have you tried? In this way we can start a discussion from there...

Answer (score 1):

In the selectMethod method you could add -

```
selectMethod = () => {
  this.setState({selected: true});
  let x = document.getElementByClassName("charge").textContent;
  // doing something with the variable 'x'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question,this can be done in following way

```
selectMethod = () => {
      document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML="sample text"
      this.setState({selected: true});
  }
```

Also add `id` attribute to to the heading tag as

```
<h2 id="heading"></h2>
```